# How to log all UDP connections in realtime with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp, wireshark

I need to list all UDP connections with Node.js. Is it possible to see all of UDP connections in console or page in realtime like in Wireshark?

Same script in Python: https://github.com/algb12/UDPGeolocate

Use case: on chatroulette sites like Omegle and Chatroulette I can see stranger IP adress in Wireshark. I want to see them in node.js console or webpage. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a UDP connection, so this isn't something you can log.

At best, you can log when you receive a packet from somewhere, with a packet capture library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap.